# How to add one element multiple times to array at once

Tags: javascript, arrays

The function should display the number of coins corresponding to a certain value; i.e: input of 56 should display back [25, 25, 5, 1].

I'm having trouble:
1) displaying 2+ of the same coin in the array (I understand the Math function below is not used correctly)
2) removing any 0s from the array

Thanks for your help.

```js
function getCoins(){
 let coins = [25, 10, 5, 1];
     amount = prompt ("Enter an amount to convert into coins");
     coinAmount = "";
     

 for (i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
  if (amount % coins[i] >= 0){ 
   coinAmount +=  coins[i] * (Math.floor (amount/coins[i])) + ","; 
   amount = amount % coins[i];   
   console.log (coinAmount)
  } 
 } 
}
  
getCoins()
```

Comment: why is `[25, 25, 5, 1]` the right result?

Comment: @NinaScholz OP has 4 types of coins `[25, 10, 5, 1]`. And here the distribution is according to the classical [coin word problems](https://www.onlinemathlearning.com/coin-problems.html)

Comment: your question is unclear and in your code u dont conver value into array.
Is your question how to make function what converts value into corresponding coins like convert(56) => [25,25,5,1] ?

Comment: I have added an answer, let me know if it helps

Comment: @ArupRakshit, i understand the problem, but not the given answer. the showed code works as i would expect the solution for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `push` the array and use `join` to display it.

You can `concat` the coinAmount to a `new Array(NumberOfCouns)` and `fill` it with the coin type.

```js
function getCoins() {
  let coins = [25, 10, 5, 1];
  let amount = prompt("Enter an amount to convert into coins");
  let coinAmount = [];


  for (i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
    if (Math.floor(amount / coins[i]) > 0) {

      coinAmount = coinAmount.concat(new Array(Math.floor(amount / coins[i])).fill(coins[i]));
      amount = amount - (Math.floor(amount / coins[i]) * coins[i]);
    }
  }

  console.log(coinAmount.join())
}

getCoins();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function getCoins(){
    let coins = [25, 10, 5, 1];
        amount = prompt ("Enter an amount to convert into coins");
        coinAmount = "";


    for (i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
        if (amount >= coins[i]){ 
            var integer = parseInt(amount/coins[i]);
            coinAmount +=  integer + ","; 
            amount -= integer*coins[i];     
            console.log (coinAmount);
        }
        else{
            coinAmount += "0,";
            console.log (coinAmount);
        }
    } 
}

getCoins()
```

for input 30:

```
1,
1,0,
1,0,1,
1,0,1,0,
```

Because we have 1 coin of value 25 and 1 coin of value 5

for input 25:

```
1,
1,0,
1,0,0,
1,0,0,0,
```